# How to change y-label step in pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I simply want to change the the labels on the y-axis to show more numbers. For example with a range from 0 - 40, it shows numbers 0, 10, 20, 30, 40.
I want to see 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 38, 39, 40.
Also I want a grid (supporting lines or how it's called) to be shown.

My code looks like this, where I have a dataframe with train dataset names, classifier names and times.
I am creating a boxplot for each classifier showing times spent on all datasets by that classifier.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## agg backend is used to create plot as a .png file
mpl.use('agg')

# read dataset
data = pd.read_csv("classifier_times_sml.csv", ";")
# extract data
g = data.sort_values("time", ascending=False)[["classifier", "train", "time"]].groupby("classifier")

# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(20, 30))
# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


labels = []
times = []
counter = 0
for group, group_df in g:
    # Create the boxplot

    times.append( np.asarray(group_df["time"]) )
    labels.append(group)

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(times, showfliers=False )
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)


# Save the figure
fig.savefig('times_sml.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I have been searching thotoughly and didn't find any useful option for the boxplot. The grid option for the ax.boxplot(...) is not allowed here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get an error if  adding `ax.grid(True)`?

Comment: no, I was actually trying to call ax.boxplot( ... , grid=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min,max,step))` or `plt.yticks(np.arange(min,max,step))`
and `ax.grid(True)` to turn on the grids.

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns;sns.set()

from numpy import arange

data = np.random.randint(0,40,size=40)
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(20, 30))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.boxplot(data)  

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 40, 1.0))
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was looking for, tho I didn't expect it to be editable this way and would like to know how exactly it knows how to align arbitrary labels with actual values of time. What If I used a series of letters?

Comment: Not sure if I am getting you correctly, but something like this ?https://imgur.com/k7ndIAJ